# match criteria to table and copy relevant data

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, match

I have a worksheet ("Worksheet A") with many columns of data. Column E contains letter data and column K contains dates.

The worksheet below ("Worksheet B") contains another set of data relevant to the combination of the column E and K data from Worksheet A.

I need to input in Column M of Worksheet A the respective data from Worksheet B. For example, if Column E contained a "C" and Column K contained "18/09/2015" the correct input would be "1.4".

If it were only across one date (e.g. 17/09/2015) I would use a formula such as:

```
=index('Worksheet B'!B2:B9, match(E2,'Worksheet B'!A2:A9,0))
```

But I don't know what to do when there are 2 variables. Any ideas?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the third criterion of INDEX() which is the column:

```
=index('Worksheet B'!B2:D9, match(E2,'Worksheet B'!A2:A9,0),match(K2,'Worksheet B'!B1:D1,0))
```